# Argument to for_each() function appears to be the wrong type

Tags: rust

I'm working thru some programming exercises on Exercism when I ran into this problem. It's not clear to me why the type of the closure set to `for_each()` even matters.
Here's the entire Rust program:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

// reformat(word) returns a tuple mapping its argument to (lowercase, sorted_lowercase)
fn reformat(word: &str) -> (String,String) {
    let lower = word.to_lowercase();
    let mut char_vec : Vec<char> = lower.chars().collect();
    char_vec.sort_unstable();
    let sorted : String = char_vec.iter().collect();
    (lower,sorted)
}

// Items in 'possible_anagrams' will be added to the set if they contain all of the
// same characters as 'word' but arranged in a different order.
fn anagrams_for<'a>(word: &str, possible_anagrams: &'a [&str]) -> HashSet<&'a str> {
    let mut set = HashSet::<&str>::new();
    let w = reformat(word);
    let is_anagram = |x:&str|->bool{let t=reformat(x);w.1==t.1&&w.0!=t.0};
    possible_anagrams.iter().filter(|x|is_anagram(x)).for_each(|x| set.insert(x));
    set
}

fn main() {
    let a : [&str; 4] = ["FRBA", "Braf", "wut", "batt"];
    println!("{:#?}", anagrams_for("Frab", &a));
}
```

I get an error message about the argument to the `for_each()` here:

```
       |
    18 |     possible_anagrams.iter().filter(|x|is_anagram(x)).for_each(|x| set.insert(x));
       |                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
expected `()`, found `bool`
```

The error message is not at all clear to me. I've tried various remedies but any change I make seems to make matters worse, i.e., more error messages.

I have a completely different manifestation of the `anagrams_for()` function that does work properly. So as far as the coding exercise goes, I have solved it via the following version of this function:

```
pub fn anagrams_for<'a>(word: &str, possible_anagrams: &'a[&str]) -> HashSet<&'a str> {
    let mut set = HashSet::<&str>::new();
    let w = reformat(word);
    for x in possible_anagrams {
        let test = reformat(x);
        if w.1 == test.1 && w.0 != test.0 {
            set.insert(x);
        }
    }
    set
}
```

This one functions as I want. I've included it here as an example of what I want the so-far-not-working code to do.

Comment: Please show the **full** error message.

Comment: Opened a PR to make the compiler suggests the fix: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/97371/.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I thought I had included the whole thing. Did you mean the "rustc-- explain E0???" as well? I guess that does provide extra info. Thx for the PR.

Comment: No, not `rustc --explain`, that is something we can run for ourselves if we feel the need. I meant what the compiler outputs (you can omit the "For more information" etc.). You omitted the "error[E0308]: mismatched types".

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I didn't get that message (error[E0308]: mismatched types).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`HashSet::insert()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html#method.insert) returns `bool` (`true` if the value was already in the set).

[`Iterator::for_each()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.for_each) expects its closure to return the unit type `()`, or "nothing" (`void` in C).

Rust is expression-oriented: (almost) everything is an expression. Closures (and functions) returns the value of their last expression. That is, `|| expr` is the same as `|| { return expr; }`, and thus your closure returns the return value of `insert()` - a `bool`, while `for_each()` expects it to return `()`.

The fix is simple: you just need to discard `insert()`'s return value. It is done by making it into a statement, by appending a semicolon to it. This will also require you to use a block:

```rust
possible_anagrams.iter().filter(|x| is_anagram(x)).for_each(|x| { set.insert(x); });
```

Comment: @Logicrat make sure to click the check mark on this answer to mark it as resolved.